# Wiring Spring constructor through annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am wiring a class with the help of Spring annotations :

```
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private B b ;

    @Value("${foo}")
    private String c ;

    @Value("${bar}")
    private Integer i ;

    public MyClass (B b, String c, Integer i) {
            this.b = b ;
            this.c = c ;
            this.i = i ;
    }
}
```

I want to remove the annotations from the fields, and move them to the constructor :

```
public class MyClass {

    private B b ;

    private String c ;

    private Integer i ;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass (B b, @Value("${foo}") String c, @Value("${bar}") Integer i) {
            this.b = b ;
            this.c = c ;
            this.i = i ;
    }
}
```

Is the above a good way to do it? It makes the class less beautiful. Is there any other way to do it using annotations ?

**Also, does it mean that b is Autowired, and c and i are wired through @Value ? That is, does the use of @Value annotation here override the @Autowired annotation for c and i ?**

P.S. : I am putting the annotations on the constructor, as I don't want to write setters, to only test the class. So I have to write a constructor that takes arguments, and gives me an object which has all the fields set. The problem with Spring is, that if I put arguments on the fields, and write a constructor that takes arguments, then I would have to write a no argument constructor also, which I don't want to do, since that would mean that in the test for this class, I could call the no argument constructor to create an object, and then call the setters to set the fields.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would not use autowiring at all but inject args into constructor from bean definition.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final B b ;
    private final String c ;
    private final Integer i ;

    public MyClass (B b, String c, Integer i) {
            this.b = b ;
            this.c = c ;
            this.i = i ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to do it through xml or annotations. I want to do it through annotations.

Answer (score 0):

With the first example, you don't need the parameters in the constructor (if it at all works).  It's basically a matter of personal preferences, but it does have some implications:

- The second approach is easier to use in tests (if you didn't have to parameters in the constructor in the first example, and without resorting to "reflection hacks")
- The second approach ensures that all fields are properly initialized before it's used also when it's used without Spring

However, there are some situations where Spring require your bean to have a default constructor with no arguments to be able to instantiate your bean, and in that case, you have to use the first approach. Typically, this occurs in some situations when you're using AspectJ/AOP/Proxy. I can't think of a concrete example right now, but I have encountered it a couple of times.

Personally, I always use the second approach as long as I can.